# What are the benefits of installing Express.js locally vs globally

Tags: node.js, express

As I understand it, there are two ways to install Express.js.

1. Using `npm install express` - either from package.json or via command line. This method will install express locally in your node_modules folder.
2. Using `npm install express -g` . This method installs the package globally on your machine.

I was just wondering what the benefits were to using either method. Is either one considered "best practice" over the other?

Comment: keeps all your code in one place. and sometimes you don't have permission to install globally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For creating an app, you should always install it locally. This will allow you to use different express version for each app you make.

Installing express globally will allow you to use the `express` command line utility to create boilerplate code and stuff. So ideally, you should install express in both places, but make sure the app you develop run on the local version.

Comment: So there is a `diff` between the `local` and the `global` express package? I use express in a lot of apps and thought I just install it global.

Comment: @Timo it is the same code in both; but I would use it differently. Dependencies used to run your app should always be locked inside your project package.json so the project can keep running in the future - and on production which will not be setup like your dev computer.

Comment: thanks, Yes and no, I use github pages in prod, and try to use the most recent version of a plugin in dev. If my code needs an older version, I try to adapt the code to the latest. This is what I can expect from Github, and am sure they try to keep up. So dev and prod will have the latest versions.